# Android Listview Change Image based on Position

Tags: android, listview, icons, position

Hello I have a listview set up with an icon to the left of each row using a row.xml. When the activity is started i would like to have one icon but when a the menu is opened and an item there is selected i want to change the icon in just one position. For example

```
I Cat
I Dog
I Mouse
I Food
```

Where I is my icon and the rest then the rest is my list i would like to change just the I in the second position so that the list would look like this

```
I Cat
D Dog
I Mouse
I Food
```

So some how get all the positions and then do like

```
for (position 1){
change the imageview
}
```

But i still want the first listview to be the default how can i change the icon of just one row? Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing this

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) lView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's your underlying data structure that you're binding to? If it's a Cursor you could call notifyChange on a Content resolver to let the adapter know the data has been updated.